# Как выполнить загрузку (функцию) только один раз?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть такой пример:

```
$(window).on('resize', function(){
if ($(document).width() < 992) {
$('#cov').load('18.html #imgs>a.photos');
}
});
```

Когда меняешь размер окна, загружается заново. Как сделать так, чтобы при данном условие сработало только один раз.

Какие техники/методы есть?

Если можете, приведите, пожалуйста примеры.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ($('#cov').find('a.photos').length == 0)
  $('#cov').load('18.html #imgs>a.photos');
```